# CakeEmail not working

Tags: cakephp, cakeemail

This my code in cakephp method in one of my controller  , but no email is coming to account. I really need help on this.

When I printing `$cc` variable , its giving an output of array , but  dont know how to know whether mail has been send successfully or  not .

Since no mail came to the mailaccount , so i guess mail is not sende properly , or there is some bug in my code .

```
$email = new CakeEmail('default');
$body = "<html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
        </head>
        <body>
            <div style='background: #F6F6F6; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; margin: 0; padding: 0;'>
                <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0' height='100%' width='100%'>
                    <tr>
                        <td align='center' valign='top' style='padding: 20px 0 20px 0'>
                            <table bgcolor='FFFFFF' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='10' border='0' width='624' style='border:1px solid #E0E0E0;'>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width='147' align='center'><img src='".Router::url('/', true)."images/logo.png'></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr bgcolor='#666666'>
                                    <td colspan='2' align='center'>
                                    Forgot Password
                                    </td> 
                                </tr>
                                <tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
                                    <td colspan='2'>Hello Admin, </td>         
                                </tr>
                                <tr bgcolor='#E7E6EC'>
                                    <td> </td> 
                                    <td width='415'>Your new password : ".$new_password."</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>";

$email->from(array($adminemail =>"Cakeshop"));
$email->emailFormat('both');
//$email->to($check['AdminLogin']['admin_email_address']);
$email->to(array($adminemail));
$email->subject('Recover Password');

$cc=$email->send($body);
```

Comment: please try var_dump($cc) and check the email send status , it will Boolean return

Comment: it returned an array of data

Comment: shared your return output array.

Comment: Have you configured your email settings correctly? You could test it with something like mailcatcher

Comment: Array ( [headers] => From: soumik.chakraborty@webguru-development.com X-Mailer: CakePHP Email Date: Thu, 14 May 2015 12:14:37 +0000 Message-ID: <555491adb7ac415ba3f605f0c0baee28@developersserver.com> MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit [message] =>
Forgot Password
Hello Admin,
 Your new password : nmszwd

Comment: I can't believe i'm the first person to say this but check the logs inside /app/tmp/logs this will show you if any errors are being generated you aren't seeing.

Also might help adding the email setting minus the password of course for us to take a look at.

Answer (score 0):

When trying something like this I would use a different method, instead of writing your markup and assigning it to the $body variable. Create a layout and view for emails, and use that as your markup. (SEE BELOW)

1. Make sure you have setup your email.php file correctly, I like to use a Gmail account to send them at first just to be sure the email functionality is working.

   public $gmail = array(
       'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
       'port' => '465',
       'username' => 'Your Gmail email',
       'password' => 'Your Gmail password',
       'transport' => 'Smtp',
       'tls' => true`enter code here`
   );
2. Once you have done this add the following code to your controller.

   $data = 'I am sending this string to the view of the email, I can then access this string using $myData';

   $Email = new CakeEmail();
   $Email->template('welcome', 'fancy')
       ->emailFormat('both')
       ->to('Email address to be sent to')
       ->from('Email address coming from.'),
       ->viewVars(array('myData' => $data))
       ->send();
3. Build the markup for your email you can find the files here.

app/View/Emails/html/welcome.ctp
app/View/Layouts/Emails/html/fancy.ctp

If you have any further questions please feel free to email me:

simpsond1988@gmail.com